# Could one explain significant performance difference in char-by-char iteration over j.l.String?

Tags: java, string, performance, benchmarking

I've tried two ways to iterate char-by-char over java.lang.String and found them confusing. The benchmark summarizes it:

```java
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = {"-Xms2g", "-Xmx2g"})
public class CharByCharIterationBenchmark {

  @Benchmark
  public void toCharArray(Data data, Blackhole b) {
    char[] chars = data.string.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : chars) {
      b.consume(ch);
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void charAt(Data data, Blackhole b) {
    String string = data.string;
    int length = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      b.consume(string.charAt(i));
    }
  }

  @State(Scope.Thread)
  public static class Data {
    String string;

    @Param({"true", "false"})
    private boolean latin;

    @Param({"5", "10", "50", "100"})
    private int length;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
      String alphabet = latin
        ? "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"        // English
        : "абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюя"; // Russian

      RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator();

      string = generator.randomString(alphabet, length);
    }
  }
```

Intuitively the approach described in `toCharArray()` seems to be less effective as it allocates a copy of underlying `char[]` as of Java 8 and encodes `byte[]` into `char[]` as of Java 9 and newer. In practise however it's vice versa: `toCharArray()` performs much faster:

```
Java 8

                                 (latin)  (length)  Mode      Score     Error   Units
charAt                              true         5  avgt     21.051 ±   0.796   ns/op
charAt                              true        10  avgt     44.002 ±   2.324   ns/op
charAt                              true        50  avgt    221.068 ±   7.422   ns/op
charAt                              true       100  avgt    410.162 ±  13.441   ns/op

toCharArray                         true         5  avgt     16.819 ±   0.662   ns/op
toCharArray                         true        10  avgt     28.364 ±   0.663   ns/op
toCharArray                         true        50  avgt    110.910 ±   1.144   ns/op
toCharArray                         true       100  avgt    205.694 ±   1.669   ns/op

charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          true         5  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          true        10  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          true        50  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          true       100  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op

toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     true         5  avgt     32.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     true        10  avgt     40.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     true        50  avgt    120.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     true       100  avgt    216.000 ±   0.001    B/op

charAt                              false        5  avgt     20.372 ±   0.406   ns/op
charAt                              false       10  avgt     39.962 ±   0.911   ns/op
charAt                              false       50  avgt    201.337 ±   3.752   ns/op
charAt                              false      100  avgt    410.530 ±  17.931   ns/op

toCharArray                         false        5  avgt     15.767 ±   0.606   ns/op
toCharArray                         false       10  avgt     26.258 ±   0.345   ns/op
toCharArray                         false       50  avgt    109.631 ±   1.064   ns/op
toCharArray                         false      100  avgt    205.815 ±   4.716   ns/op

charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false        5  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false       10  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false       50  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false      100  avgt     ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op

toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false        5  avgt     32.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false       10  avgt     40.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false       50  avgt    120.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false      100  avgt    216.000 ±   0.001    B/op


Java 11


                                  (latin)  (length)  Mode     Score     Error   Units
charAt                               true         5  avgt    22.035 ±   1.557   ns/op
charAt                               true        10  avgt    41.800 ±   1.572   ns/op
charAt                               true        50  avgt   227.180 ±  18.655   ns/op
charAt                               true       100  avgt   474.719 ±  29.782   ns/op

toCharArray                          true         5  avgt    17.091 ±   0.662   ns/op
toCharArray                          true        10  avgt    26.167 ±   0.220   ns/op
toCharArray                          true        50  avgt   127.876 ±   2.106   ns/op
toCharArray                          true       100  avgt   244.449 ±   9.330   ns/op

charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm           true         5  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm           true        10  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm           true        50  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm           true       100  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op

toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      true         5  avgt    32.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      true        10  avgt    40.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      true        50  avgt   120.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      true       100  avgt   216.000 ±   0.001    B/op

charAt                              false         5  avgt    22.215 ±   2.064   ns/op
charAt                              false        10  avgt    45.606 ±   2.567   ns/op
charAt                              false        50  avgt   204.577 ±  18.302   ns/op
charAt                              false       100  avgt   404.056 ±  10.203   ns/op

toCharArray                         false         5  avgt    17.055 ±   0.556   ns/op
toCharArray                         false        10  avgt    29.254 ±   2.616   ns/op
toCharArray                         false        50  avgt   123.610 ±   5.033   ns/op
toCharArray                         false       100  avgt   226.174 ±   6.396   ns/op

charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false         5  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false        10  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false        50  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op
charAt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm          false       100  avgt    ≈ 10⁻⁴              B/op

toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false         5  avgt    32.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false        10  avgt    40.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false        50  avgt   120.000 ±   0.001    B/op
toCharArray:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     false       100  avgt   216.000 ±   0.001    B/op
```

First I was thinking that reason here is the same as descrbed in Nitsan Wakart's article ["Volatile read surprise"](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2014/08/the-volatile-read-suprise.html). However doing profiling with perfasm I see that the hottest spots in the code are not related to `char[]`/`byte[]` field access:

```
           ╭│     0x00007fa638407dd9: jmp    0x00007fa638407e4c
           ││     0x00007fa638407ddb: nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4.96%    ││  ↗  0x00007fa638407de0: shl    $0x3,%r11
  0.01%    ││  │  0x00007fa638407de4: movzwl 0x10(%r11,%r13,2),%edx  ;*invokevirtual charAt {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           ││  │                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@25 (line 35)
           ││  │                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  3.58%    ││ ↗│  0x00007fa638407dea: mov    %rsi,0x18(%rsp)
  1.87%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407def: mov    %r8d,0x14(%rsp)
  4.18%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407df4: mov    %edi,0x10(%rsp)
  0.04%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407df8: mov    %rbx,0x8(%rsp)
  1.29%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407dfd: mov    %r10,(%rsp)
  1.83%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407e01: mov    %r9,0x70(%rsp)
  4.32%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407e06: mov    %rax,0x60(%rsp)
  0.05%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407e0b: mov    %r9,%rsi
  1.27%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407e0e: nop
  1.88%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407e0f: callq  0x00007fa630926e00  ; ImmutableOopMap{[96]=Oop [104]=Oop [112]=Oop [120]=Oop [0]=Oop [16]=NarrowOop [24]=Oop }
           ││ ││                                                ;*invokevirtual consume {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           ││ ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@28 (line 35)
           ││ ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
           ││ ││                                                ;   {optimized virtual_call}
  5.71%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407e14: inc    %ebp               ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           ││ ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@31 (line 34)
           ││ ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  0.05%    ││ ││  0x00007fa638407e16: cmp    0x14(%rsp),%ebp
  0.00%    │╰ ││  0x00007fa638407e1a: jge    0x00007fa638407d87  ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@18 (line 34)
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  3.05%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e20: mov    0x10(%rsp),%edi
  4.24%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e24: movsbl 0x14(%r12,%rdi,8),%ecx  ;*getfield coder {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │  ││                                                ; - java.lang.String::isLatin1@7 (line 3266)
           │  ││                                                ; - java.lang.String::charAt@1 (line 692)
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@25 (line 35)
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  0.86%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e2a: mov    0xc(%r12,%rdi,8),%r11d  ;*getfield value {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │  ││                                                ; - java.lang.String::charAt@8 (line 693)
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@25 (line 35)
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  1.67%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e2f: mov    0x60(%rsp),%rax
  1.71%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e34: mov    0x70(%rsp),%r9
  3.92%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e39: mov    (%rsp),%r10
  0.20%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e3d: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rbx
  1.44%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e42: mov    0x14(%rsp),%r8d
  1.70%    │  ││  0x00007fa638407e47: mov    0x18(%rsp),%rsi    ;*aload_2 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@21 (line 35)
           │  ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  3.93%    ↘  ││  0x00007fa638407e4c: movslq %ebp,%r13          ;*invokestatic getChar {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
              ││                                                ; - java.lang.StringUTF16::charAt@7 (line 1268)
              ││                                                ; - java.lang.String::charAt@21 (line 695)
              ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@25 (line 35)
              ││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  0.23%       ││  0x00007fa638407e4f: test   %ecx,%ecx
  0.00%      ╭││  0x00007fa638407e51: jne    0x00007fa638407e6b  ;*ifeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
             │││                                                ; - java.lang.String::charAt@4 (line 692)
             │││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@25 (line 35)
             │││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
             │││  0x00007fa638407e53: mov    0xc(%r12,%r11,8),%edx  ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007fa638407fbc
             │││  0x00007fa638407e58: cmp    %edx,%ebp
             │││  0x00007fa638407e5a: jae    0x00007fa638407eb0
             │││  0x00007fa638407e5c: shl    $0x3,%r11
             │││  0x00007fa638407e60: movzbl 0x10(%r11,%r13,1),%edx  ;*iand {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
             │││                                                ; - java.lang.StringLatin1::charAt@25 (line 49)
             │││                                                ; - java.lang.String::charAt@12 (line 693)
             │││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@25 (line 35)
             │││                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
             │╰│  0x00007fa638407e66: jmpq   0x00007fa638407dea
  1.52%      ↘ │  0x00007fa638407e6b: mov    0xc(%r12,%r11,8),%ecx  ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007fa638407fb0
  5.99%        │  0x00007fa638407e70: sar    %ecx               ;*ishr {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
               │                                                ; - java.lang.StringUTF16::length@3 (line 74)
               │                                                ; - java.lang.StringUTF16::checkIndex@2 (line 1470)
               │                                                ; - java.lang.StringUTF16::charAt@2 (line 1267)
               │                                                ; - java.lang.String::charAt@21 (line 695)
               │                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.CharByCharIterationBenchmark::charAt@25 (line 35)
               │                                                ; - tsypanov.strings.character.generated.CharByCharIterationBenchmark_charAt_jmhTest::charAt_avgt_jmhStub@19 (line 191)
  5.51%        │  0x00007fa638407e72: cmp    %ecx,%ebp
  0.01%        ╰  0x00007fa638407e74: jb     0x00007fa638407de0  ;*if_icmplt {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
```

It looks like the hottest place is `iinc` (increment of loop index) and `ishr` arythmetic shift in `StringUTF16.length()` which is rather conter-intuitive to me.

Also using perfnorm profiler I see that `toCharArray()` has less cycles, instructions and load-misses comparing to `chatAt()`:

```
Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt     Score   Error  Units

charAt:L1-dcache-loads             avgt       2104.816           #/op
charAt:L1-dcache-stores            avgt       1200.878           #/op
charAt:branches                    avgt        603.754           #/op
charAt:cycles                      avgt       1461.282           #/op
charAt:dTLB-loads                  avgt       2105.253           #/op
charAt:dTLB-stores                 avgt       1200.909           #/op
charAt:instructions                avgt       4716.775           #/op

toCharArray:L1-dcache-loads        avgt       1026.341           #/op
toCharArray:L1-dcache-stores       avgt        416.997           #/op
toCharArray:branches               avgt        419.265           #/op
toCharArray:cycles                 avgt        820.521           #/op
toCharArray:dTLB-loads             avgt       1026.506           #/op
toCharArray:dTLB-stores            avgt        417.591           #/op
toCharArray:instructions           avgt       2409.806           #/op
```

Could someone help to interpret this and explain such significant difference?

Comment: Intuitively speaking, each time you call `charAt`, it checks whether the string is encoded in UTF-16 or Latin1, and also checks whether the index passed is within bounds. For array access, bounds checking can be optimized to check the loop bounds rather than checking each index.

Comment: It might be up to the array being scalar replaced (there are different optimization rules for loads from scalar replaced objects). You could try adding another benchmark where you create the char[] in advance, and then load it from Data in the benchmark method (just like with the String), and see if there's a difference in time then as well (just a hunch though).

Comment: @JornVernee `toCharArray` is *not* scalar replaced. Note `gc.alloc.rate.norm` in the results.

Comment: The problem is that `BlackHole.consume` is called *inside* the loop. Being a non-inlined black box method, it prevents from optimizing the code around the call, in particular, caching String fields.

Comment: BTW, `iinc` and `ishr` are not the hottest. perf often attributes execution time to the following instruction(s) (look for "perf event skid").

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114891/loop-unswitching-optimization-is-not-working/59116238#59116238

Comment: @apangin You're right, I should have looked a little better before commenting. In this case not caching String field loads is a a bit of a missed optimization. C2 already trusts that String fields don't change when constant folding, but this trust is not being leveraged in these kinds of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @apangin mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338861/could-one-explain-significant-performance-difference-in-char-by-char-iteration-o#comment112001366_63338861)

> The problem is that BlackHole.consume is called inside the loop. Being a non-inlined black box method, it prevents from optimizing the code around the call, in particular, caching String fields.